Blender 4.2 - Need help exporting .obj material with both Kd and map_Kd attributes for image textured objects
I'm creating scenery for a glider flight simulation program called Condor2.  The Condor2 object editor requires image textured objects to have both map_Kd  and Kd  attributes in the .mtl file created by the export from Blender.
If there is a way to accomplish this without modifying the export script, I have not been able to discover it.
Otherwise, I'd appreciate some guidance in how best to modify the export code (or even just 'post-process the .mtl file).  All I need is a line with 'Kd 1.0 1.0 1.0' added to any material that includes a map_Kd attribute.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions, tips, HOWTO pointers.
David
